# Add zero prefix of the number in Perl for date conversion

Tags: perl

I'm trying to add zero prefix of the number. I have tried the code as follows,

**Code:**

```
use strict;
   use warnings;
   my $day = 11;
   for (my $i=1; $i<=$day ; $i++) {
       if( $i < 10 ) {
            $i = "0$i";
        }
        print "Number of day: $i\n";
    }
```

**Output:**

```
01
002
0003
00004
...
...
```

But I want the output like below,

```
01
02
03
04
...
```

Please help me on this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $day = 11;
for (my $i=1; $i<=$day; $i++) {
    if( $i < 10 ) {
        $i = sprintf("%02d",$i);
    }
    print "Number of day: $i\n";
}
```